# Поиск элемента List<Object>

Tags: android, объекты, arraylist

Есть List которая хранит экземпляры класса Object. Каждый экземпляр имеет поля id и name. Нужно вывести значение name (допустим в Toast) того объекта, который равен некоему заданному id.

Comment: и что вызывает вопросы? У Вас же, наверное, есть какой-то код, как Вы пытались решить эту задачу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java:

```
MyObject getById(int id) {
    for (MyObject o: list) {
        if (o.id == id) {
            return o;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

Для API >= 24
MyObject getById(int id) {
    return list.stream()
            .filter(o -> o.id == id)
            .findAny()
            .orElse(null);
}
```

Kotlin:

```
fun getById(id: Int) = list.find {
    it.id == id
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло )